# Insert values of rows above python

Tags: python

I have a csv below:

```
ID    Date          Time       Flag
1     14/05/2018    00:01:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:02:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:03:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:04:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:05:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:06:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:07:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:08:00   NaN
1     15/05/2018    00:01:00   1
1     15/05/2018    00:02:00   1
1     16/05/2018    00:01:00   1
1     16/05/2018    00:02:00   1

2     10/07/2018    00:03:00   NaN
2     10/07/2018    00:04:00   NaN
2     10/07/2018    00:05:00   NaN
2     10/07/2018    00:06:00   NaN
2     10/07/2018    00:07:00   NaN
2     10/07/2018    00:08:00   NaN
2     11/07/2018    00:01:00   1
2     11/07/2018    00:02:00   1
2     12/07/2018    00:01:00   1
2     12/07/2018    00:02:00   1
```

I want to update NaN for only 4 rows above the first row (of only the first day and first time of that day) with Flag=1 for each ID.

Expected csv:

```
1     14/05/2018    00:01:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:02:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:03:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:04:00   NaN
1     14/05/2018    00:05:00   1
1     14/05/2018    00:06:00   1
1     14/05/2018    00:07:00   1
1     14/05/2018    00:08:00   1
1     15/05/2018    00:01:00   1
1     15/05/2018    00:02:00   1
1     16/05/2018    00:01:00   1
1     16/05/2018    00:02:00   1

2     10/07/2018    00:03:00   NaN
2     10/07/2018    00:04:00   NaN
2     10/07/2018    00:05:00   1
2     10/07/2018    00:06:00   1
2     10/07/2018    00:07:00   1
2     10/07/2018    00:08:00   1
2     11/07/2018    00:01:00   1
2     11/07/2018    00:02:00   1
2     12/07/2018    00:01:00   1
2     12/07/2018    00:02:00   1
```

How can I do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're changing all `Flag` values to 1:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv.csv')
df['Flag'] = 1
df.to_csv('path/to/csv.csv', index=False)
```

If, however, you don't want to update all `Flag` values, check out either [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for accessing specific parts of your `DataFrame`.

Comment: but I only want 4 rows above the first day with Flag=1 for each ID

Comment: @Jason You can update a range of values of your `DataFrame` like so: `df.loc[0:4, 'Flag'] = 1`, but also please change your expected csv in your question to match this requirement

Comment: I have updated the expected csv. However, I do not understand how your code can achieve this. I only want 4 rows above the first day and first time of that day (each ID) to be updated to 1. I will then use Flag != 1 to remove all other rows.

Comment: You can filter `DataFrame`s like so: `filtered_df = df[df['Flag'] !=1]`. I recommend checking out pandas tutorials to get an additional sense of how pandas `DataFrame`s work

Comment: but you still have not got to the point. That is 4 rows above the first day and first time of that day for each ID. The filter part comes later after Flag is updated for that 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine a few different commands. To find the first row for each ID, use pandas groupby on multiple columns, `ID` and `Date`, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
filtered_df = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])
```

After that you can copy the original dataframe based on the `Date` and `Time` of the `filtered_df`